# Problems Using scipy's curve_fit to Estimate Negative Exponential Parameters

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to get scipy's `curves_fit` function to estimate the parameters of a modified negative exponential function. I'm getting errors when I call `curve_fit` and I've no idea why.

The function is defined as:

```
def negative_exponential(x, carryover, asymptote, speed):
    return x[0] * carryover + asymptote * (1 - np.exp(-speed * x[1]))
```

This seems to work as expected when called with reasonable parameters

The data used to estimate the parameters is stored in a dataframe. Here's the code I've used to call `curve_fit`

```
x = df[["Sales_2015", "Calls_2016"]]
y = df["Sales_2016"]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(negative_exponential, x.values, y.values)
print (popt)
```

The `curve_fit` function gives this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\steve\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2133             try:
-> 2134                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2135             except KeyError:
```

I have also tried calling `curve_fit` by passing the x.values and y.values. This also gave an error.

Note also I have no problem estimating an OLS model using this data e.g.

```
model = sm.OLS(y, x).fit()
model.summary()
```

Which implies I need to do something to `x` and `y` before passing to `curve_fit`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide some data? What do you mean by "it seems to work with reasonable parameters"?

Comment: Yes - here some [test data](http://czmx.co/qqO7/IHTefLEg). The series names match those in the explanation.

Comment: By reasonable parameters, I mean when called directly it gives the expected result e.g.`negative_exponential([10, 5], 0.6, 100, 0.2)` gives `69.21`

Comment: Have you checked the docs for `curve_fit`? The docstring clearly states that the xdata should be of (k,M) shape, but you seem to pass an (M,k) shape instead.

Comment: @VlasSokolov Thanks!! That was the problem! Changing these two lines fixed everything!

    x = d4[["Sales_2015", "Calls_2016"]].transpose().as_matrix()
    y = d4["Sales_2016"].transpose().as_matrix()

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the dimension of x and y. Transposing the dataframe series fixed the code:

```
x = d4[["Sales_2015", "Calls_2016"]].transpose().as_matrix()
y = d4["Sales_2016"].transpose().as_matrix()
```